# Checking multiple values through arrays, should return one value

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I return one value after all the checks?
In this example, the method checkInterval() is called four times and overwrites the result.
If at least one value from const VALUES is out of range (PRESCRIPTION_RULES), I need to return false.

```js
const PRESCRIPTION_RULES = {
    interval: {
        SPH: [{min: -2, max: 2}],
        CYL: [{min: -2, max: 2}],
    },
};

class CheckRules {

    check() {

        const values = [
            {name: 'sph_od', value: -2},
            {name: 'sph_os', value: -2},
            {name: 'cyl_os', value: -5},
            {name: 'cyl_od', value: -1},
        ];

        values.map(obj => {
            if (obj.name === 'sph_od' || obj.name === 'sph_os') {
               this.checkInterval(obj.value, PRESCRIPTION_RULES.interval.SPH);
            } else if (obj.name === 'cyl_od' || obj.name === 'cyl_os') {
              this.checkInterval(obj.value, PRESCRIPTION_RULES.interval.CYL);
            }
        });

    }

    checkInterval(current, packages) {
        let result = [];

        packages.map(obj => {
            if (obj.min <= current && obj.max >= current) {
               result.push(true);
            }
            else {
                result.push(false);
            }
        });
        
        const shouldReturnOneValue = result.every(elem => elem === true);
        console.log(shouldReturnOneValue);
    }

}

const rules = new CheckRules();
rules.check();
```

This is a simplified version of my class, I removed everything that is irrelevant. I have a lot PRESCRIPTION_RULES and VALUES

link to sandbox https://jsbin.com/qoweyow/edit?js,console

Comment: what return value do you expect?

Comment: why `map` instead of `forEach`?

Comment: in this sample should return false because one of values   {name: 'cyl_os', value: -5} if out of range

Answer (score 1):

Provided you expect check() to return a boolean if all the rules are respected:

Make checkInterval return the value of result.every() :

```
checkInterval(current, packages) {
        // you can use filter here instead of map to filter eleements, then every
        return packages.filter(obj => {
           return obj.min <= current && obj.max >= current 
        }).every(elem => elem === true);
    }
```

in check(), change map into every and return the result

```
return values.every(obj => {
            if (obj.name === 'sph_od' || obj.name === 'sph_os') {
               return this.checkInterval(obj.value, PRESCRIPTION_RULES.interval.SPH);
            } else if (obj.name === 'cyl_od' || obj.name === 'cyl_os') {
              return this.checkInterval(obj.value, PRESCRIPTION_RULES.interval.CYL);
            }
        });
```